# AutoMapper: passing 2 elements to the resolution context

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using AutoMapper to retreive an Order object. For the price, I resolve using an extension method of the object and I need to pass in a `PriceType` and a `Markup` for the calculation.

Currently, I have it working for just `PriceType`

```
//in the mapping
    .ForMember(d => d.TotalPrice, opt => opt.ResolveUsing((src, dest, destMember, resContext) => dest.TotalPrice= src.UserTotalPrice((string)resContext.Items["Pricing"])))
//pass in the variable
    var s = Mapper.Map<Order, NewOrder>(order, opts => opts.Items["Pricing"] = "A");
```

I need to pass in the markup

```
//in the mapping
    .ForMember(d => d.TotalPrice, opt => opt.ResolveUsing((src, dest, destMember, resContext) => dest.TotalPrice= src.UserTotalPrice((string)resContext.Items["Pricing"]),(decimal)resContext.Items["Markup"]))
```

**Question:** How can I set 2 elements with passing it in?

```
 var s = Mapper.Map<Order, NewOrder>(order, opts => opts.Items["Pricing"] = "A"**********missing code**************);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
opts => 
{
   opts.Items["Pricing"] = "A";
   opts.Items["Markup"] = 12;
}
```

Comment: You can also have a class with `Pricing` and `Markup` members and then you need only one key, perhaps the name of that class.